# Add icon to the bottom div section based on browser height

Tags: html, css

Here is the thing.. I have a web page split to 2 sections (`intro` and `main`)

[image: Webpage]

The `intro` section stretches to 100 based on the browser height with CSS:

```
#intro {
  height: 100vh;
}
```

I want to add an arrow with href that will be positioned at the bottom section of the `intro` div no matter which screen size is entering the page.

Do you have any idea how can it be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
#intro {
    ...
    position: relative; /* or absolute, as appropriate */
}
#down_arrow {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -25px; /* half the element's width */
}
```

This assumes markup similar to the following. In the future, please provide your markup in your question.

```
<div id="intro">
    <div id="down_arrow"> ... </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `position:relative` to the `#intro` element and `position:absolute` to the arrow.

Also give a bottom and left rule:

```
#arrow {
    width:40px;  /* sample width - set as you wish */
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-20px;  /* important: set half of the width (centers the div) */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
margin-top:90vh
```

:D and I need to write some text so stackoverflow knows I'm not spamming.

Rich homie quan is a good rapper. I think the limit has been reached, now.

Answer (score 0):

Did You mean something like this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ukem69m8/)
I use positioning of intro element as `relative` and set this **viewportheight** as you want. 
So if i set arrow postion to `absolute` it will stay inside intro element.

```
.arrow{
width: 50px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -25px;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the case :)

Answer (score 0):

Using flexbox ([demo](http://codepen.io/tomesch/pen/LVORXd)):

```
<div class="intro">
  <div class="nav"></div>
    <div class="link-container">
      <a>Arrow</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="main"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.intro {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: blue;
}

.intro > .link-container {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.section2 {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
}
#intro {
  position: relative;
}
```

Add appropriate styles to make it as center of the screen.

Answer (score -1):

Place the arrow inside of the intro container and use:

```
.arrow{
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

you may also need to fiddle around with the POSITION property as well, but this should give you what you need. Hope this helps!